# Why does the "move 5 - if touching wall - move back 5" logic not work when scrolling is implemented?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I know that this sort of wall detection logic works fine in most games, but I wanted some more pizzaz. So, I implemented scrolling, where the player is always in the middle and instead, the background moves.

```
keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_w]:
    y-=5
    if rect.colliderect(wall):
        y+=5
```

The way my scrolling works is all the objects are drawn relative to the variable `scrollx` and `scrolly`. When keys are pressed, `scrollx` or `scrolly` changes. When the collision actually happens though, the player seems to get stuck in the objects. Here's the full code.

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
win_height=600
win_width=600
win=pygame.display.set_mode((win_width,win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("YourCraft")
white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
debris_list=[]

player=pygame.Rect(win_width/2,win_height/2,20,20)
scrolly=0
scrollx=0

size=1000
speed=5

class debris_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=random.randrange(0,size-20)
        self.y=random.randrange(0,size-20)
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,20,20)
    def update(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win,white,self.rect)
        self.rect.y=scrolly+self.y
        self.rect.x=scrollx+self.x

for i in range(10):
    debris=debris_class()
    debris_list.append(debris)

def collision():
    for i in debris_list:
        if i.rect.colliderect(player):
            return 1
    return 0

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_s]:
        scrolly-=speed
        collide=collision()
        if collide==1:
            scrolly+=speed

    if key[pygame.K_w]:
        scrolly+=speed
        collide=collision()
        if collide==1:
            scrolly-=speed

    if key[pygame.K_d]:
        scrollx-=speed
        collide=collision()
        if collide==1:
            scrollx+=speed

    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        scrollx+=speed
        collide=collision()
        if collide==1:
            scrollx-=speed


    win.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(win,green,(scrollx,scrolly,size,size)) #background
    pygame.draw.rect(win,white,player)

    for i in debris_list:
        i.update()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing the collision test too early. When the collision test is run, the object and map have not yet been scrolled.

Separate `update` and `draw` in the class `debris_class`:

```py
class debris_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=random.randrange(0,size-20)
        self.y=random.randrange(0,size-20)
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,20,20)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y=scrolly+self.y
        self.rect.x=scrollx+self.x
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win,white,self.rect)
```

Get the movement depending on the keys pressed and the speed:

```py
key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
move_x = (key[pygame.K_d] - key[pygame.K_a]) * speed
move_y = (key[pygame.K_s] - key[pygame.K_w]) * speed
```

Copy the plyer and move the player:

```py
player_copy = player.copy()
player.x += move_x
player.y += move_y
```

Perform the collision test and undo the movement of the player:

```py
collide = collision()
player = player_copy
```

If no collision is detected, scroll the map and the objects:

```py
if collide == 0:
    scrollx -= move_x
    scrolly -= move_y
    for i in debris_list:
        i.update()
```

Draw the objects in a loop:

```py
for i in debris_list:
    i.draw()
```

---

Complete code:

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
win_height=600
win_width=600
win=pygame.display.set_mode((win_width,win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("YourCraft")
white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
debris_list=[]

player=pygame.Rect(win_width/2,win_height/2,20,20)
scrolly=0
scrollx=0

size=1000
speed=5

class debris_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=random.randrange(0,size-20)
        self.y=random.randrange(0,size-20)
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,20,20)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y=scrolly+self.y
        self.rect.x=scrollx+self.x
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win,white,self.rect)

for i in range(10):
    debris=debris_class()
    debris_list.append(debris)

def collision():
    for i in debris_list:
        if i.rect.colliderect(player):
            return 1
    return 0

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    move_x = (key[pygame.K_d] - key[pygame.K_a]) * speed
    move_y = (key[pygame.K_s] - key[pygame.K_w]) * speed
    
    player_copy = player.copy()
    player.x += move_x
    player.y += move_y

    collide = collision()
    player = player_copy
    if collide == 0:
        scrollx -= move_x
        scrolly -= move_y
        for i in debris_list:
            i.update()
           
    win.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(win,green,(scrollx,scrolly,size,size)) #background
    pygame.draw.rect(win,white,player)
    for i in debris_list:
        i.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Oh I've seen that method of collision before, but I totally forgot about it. Very nice.

Comment: @bad_coder Thank you. You're welcome. However, I was not satisfied with my solution and improved it.